# instagram authorization without popup

Tags: authentication, embedded, instagram

I'm trying to develop an Instagram app for embedded systems, where the user has control with remote. Is it possible to authenticate the user to the application without being redirected to the Instagram login page itself?

Answer (score 0):

I don't KNOW, but I would say it's unlikely, since this would open a pretty big security hole (who's to say you're not going to capture and store user credentials as they authenticate through your system?) Not saying this is your intention, just pointing out the possibilities

Comment: Yes, that's right. I found other solution. User gets authenticated by logging on provider website and then gets pin that can be used in a box to retreive access token. Thanks for reply.